# pip does not install my package dependencies

Tags: python, pip

I have developed a python package on github that I released on PyPi. It installs with `pip install PACKAGENAME`, but does not do anything with the dependencies that are stated in the "install_requires" of the setup.py file.

Weirdly enough, the zip file of the associated release does install all dependencies.. I tried with different virtual environments and on different computers but it never installs the dependencies.. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Show us your actual `setup.py`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`pip install pythutils` downloads a wheel if it's available — and [it's available](https://pypi.org/project/pythutils/1.1.1/#files) for your package.

When generating a wheel `setuptools` runs `python setup.py` **locally** but doesn't include `setup.py` into the wheel. Download your [wheel file](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/08/470c9b591333ac81802a0ca37c7b5bf8f099037ce112e5dd1ecb3eba7022/pythutils-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl) and unzip it (it's just a zip archive) — there is your main package directory `pythutils` and a directory with metadata `pythutils-1.1.1.dist-info`. In the metadata directory there is a file `METADATA` that usually lists **static** dependencies but your file doesn't list any. Because when you were generating wheels all your dependencies has already been installed so all your dynamic code paths were skipped.

The archive that you downloaded from Github release install dependencies because it's not a wheel so `pip` runs `python setup.py install` and your dynamic dependencies work.

What you can do? My advice is to avoid dynamic dependencies. Declare static dependencies and allow `pip` to decide what versions to install:

```
install_requires=[
    'numpy==1.16.5; python_version>="2" and python_version<"3"',
    'numpy; python_version>="3"',
],
```

Another approach would be to create version-specific wheel files — one for Python 2 and another for Python 3 — with fixed dependencies.

Yet another approach is to not publish wheels at all and only publish sdist (source distribution). Then `pip` is forced to run `python setup.py install` on the target machine. That not the best approach and it certainly will be problematic for packages with C extensions (user must have a compiler and developer tools to install from sources).

Comment: Wonderful, that was very helpful. I updated the setup file to set the install_requires directly as you suggested and ran the steps to upload the next version to pypi and now it installs correctly with all dependencies on both python2.7 and python3. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Your `setup.py`](https://github.com/JolleJolles/pythutils/blob/master/setup.py)  does a series of checks like

```
try:
    import numpy
except ImportError:
    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
        install_requires.append('numpy==1.16.5')
    if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
        install_requires.append("numpy")
```

Presumably the system where you ran it had all the required modules already installed, and so ended up with an empty list in `install_requires`. But this is the wrong way to do it anyway; you should simply make a static list (or two static lists, one each for Python 2 and Python 3 if you really want to support both in the same package).

Comment: Weirdly enough I tried it with a fresh virtualenv (where pip freeze did not return anything) and then still it returned no dependencies, but I have now followed the steps in the answer by @phd below and that worked. Thanks

Comment: (Thanks for following up. There is no "above" or "below" here, though; in fact, I see phd's reply above mine right now.)