# Python package does not install dependencies

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I followed a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/) on publishing a python package. I have published the `reader` example [to TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/project/thrayld-reader-test/) and tried to install it, using the following command.

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ thrayld-reader-test
```

However, this is the response.

```
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting thrayld-reader-test
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/ba/e9d9327dae4139e4c0754a13f22a04131c65aabc5fd22fb87e99a52309f6/thrayld_reader_test-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.2 kB)
Collecting feedparser
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/45/0f86efe62f6a0e1c3347e0c409dc680fc96e7951f6ecaf19aecd5a914b01/feedparser-6.0.3a1-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 82 kB 111 kB/s
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement html2text (from thrayld-reader-test)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for html2text
```

`pip` does not download the depedendencies, only complains that they are not satisfied.

My question is why and how to fix it?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881683/pip-does-not-install-my-package-dependencies), but the solution does not apply, since I already have `install_requires` in the `setup.py` as in the example.

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        "feedparser", "html2text", "importlib_resources", "typing"
    ],
    ...
)
```

Comment: `pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple thrayld-reader-test`

Comment: The problem is that `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/` doesn't allow to install from anything other than TestPyPI and your dependencies aren't there. You need to allow to install from main PyPI using `--extra-index-url`.

Comment: Thank you. That is quite puzzling error, i.e. it appears only when testing, but now when actualy deploying.